# AOP pointcut for @After

Tags: java, casting, return-value, spring-aop, pointcut

I want AOP logging for the method's return value

```
    @After("execution(* com.dbs.tup.sample.service.*.*(..))")
    public void logAfter(JoinPoint point) {
        log.info("{} is returning {}", point.getSignature().getName(), "???");
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found this

```
    @AfterReturning(pointcut = "execution(* com.dbs.tup.sample.service.*.*(..))", returning = "retValue")
    public void logAfter(JoinPoint point, Object retValue) {
        log.info("{} is returning {}", point.getSignature().getName(), (((MethodSignature) point.getSignature()).getReturnType().cast(retValue)).toString());
    }
```

Comment: Hint: You can accept your own answer in order to close the question. :-)